# MySQL Migration tool and wbcopytables.exe

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, mysql-workbench

I have been using MySQLMigration tool, to generate script and sync from PostgreSQL to MySQL. 
This script contains tables and fields to migrate data and includes a call to command wbcopytables.exe that manage the sync operation.

I just try with a single table with 9445 rows, and when I execute and finish the process show that only copied 100 rows, but last 9345 failed to copy.

Log in PostgreSQL say:

```
> 2016-06-07 13:03:46 CEST ERROR:  carácter con secuencia de bytes 0xef
> 0xbf 0xbd en codificación «UTF8» no tiene equivalente en la
> codificación «WIN1252»
```

Depending of the table, the number of copied rows is different.

What is happening?

Comment: Well - trying to translate the Spanish(?) error message, it looks like it is complaining that you are trying to put UTF8 characters into a WIN1252 database. There are more characters in the full unicode set than in WIN1252 and your data contains some of these. You will either need to use unicode (UTF8) throughout or substitute the characters that do not fit in WIN1252

Comment: Please provide more details, like: WB, MySQL server and PostgreSQL versions, your OS, you can also include link to your log file that can be found in menu Help->Show log file

Comment: Probably changed PostgreSQL encoding and MySQL is working with UTF8?